# Get autocompletion list in bash variable

Tags: bash, autocomplete, makefile

I'm working with a big software project with many build targets. When typing `make <tab> <tab>` it shows over 1000 possible make targets. 
What I want is a bash script that filters those targets by certain rules. Therefore I would like to have this list of make targets in a bash variable.

```
make_targets=$(???)
[do something with make_targets]
make $make_targets
```

It would be best if I wouldn't have to change anything with my project.

How can I get such a List?

Answer (score 1):

@yuyichao created a [function to get autocomplete output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31023/3645):

```
comp() {
    COMP_LINE="$*"
    COMP_WORDS=("$@")
    COMP_CWORD=${#COMP_WORDS[@]}
    ((COMP_CWORD--))
    COMP_POINT=${#COMP_LINE}
    COMP_WORDBREAKS='"'"'><=;|&(:"
    # Don't really thing any real autocompletion script will rely on
    # the following 2 vars, but on principle they could ~~~  LOL.
    COMP_TYPE=9
    COMP_KEY=9
    _command_offset 0
    echo ${COMPREPLY[@]}
}
```

Just run `comp make ''` to get the results, and you can manipulate that. Example:

```
$ comp make ''
test foo clean
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to overwrite / modify the completion function for `make`. On Ubuntu it is located at:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make
```

(Other distributions may store the file at `/etc/bash_completion.d/make`)

If you don't want to change the completion behavior for the whole system, you might write a small wrapper script like `build-project`, which calls `make`. Then write a completion function for that mapper which is derived from `make`'s one.